# Vb.net image effect / colormatrix

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently using colormatrix in vb.net to apply filter like effects e.g negative, hue and brightness etc..

My question is, is colormatrix the best way to do this? Or is there another better way? Thanks

Comment: I think `ColorMatrix` is about as good as it gets for that kind of thing.